# Eclipse content assist in Android xml file like IntelliJ

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, intellij-idea, content-assist

When editing android xml files.

IntelliJ allows me to complete `android:screenOrientation` by typing `a:sc` then I get my tag first in list.
In Eclipse, I have to type `android:sc` before I get my tag on top. If I type `a:` in Eclipse it empties list.

Is there a workaround or setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can type `sc` only and press `Ctrl+space`.

Eclipse will suggests you the list of tags that starts with `android:sc`.

No need to type `android:s` to get the tags which starts with `s`.

Comment: Thank you and sry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

this method used to work for me.
But for some reason when I press `Ctrl+Space` now, eclipse auto complete without popping the proposal window, and without understanding the context. 
(if i'll type for example `si` and press `Ctrl+Space` eclipse will complete the word to a word starting with si instead of suggesting android:textsize as it used to do)